# Bash compare file last modification date with another date

Tags: bash

I need to check if the last modification date of a file if greater than a date saved in a variable like this:

```
variable=$date

if [ $file_last_modified_date -gt $variable ]; then.......
```

The error I get: `[: too many arguments`

I'm afraid, the error is because the two formats are different:

- `file_last_modified_date`: `2016-11-01 23:00:00.000000000 +0100`
- `variable`: `Wed Nov 2 16:10:52 CET 2016`

How can I make them comparable?

Comment: Wrap the parameter expansions in double quotes.

Comment: Quoting is just the tip of the iceberg here. `-gt` is for integer comparison, not string comparision. Your version of `[` *might* support `\>` to compare if one string is lexicographically greater than the other, but that really requires both strings to be in the same format.

Comment: I added double quotes and I get error: [: 2016-11-01 23:00:00.000000000 +0100: integer expression expected

Comment: @chepner: how can I make them in the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both dates to a common format that is amenable to comparison. You may be able to simply use GNU `date` to convert both to Unix epoch timestamps:

```
d1=$(date +%s --date "$file_last_modified_date")  # 1478037600
d2=$(date +%s --date "$variable")                 # 1478099452
```

Now you can compare them as integers.

```
if [ "$d1" -gt "$d2" ]; then
```